# Symfony Built-in Web Server on an external environment

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I configured a web service locally using FOSRestBundle, and it's working perfectly. The only thing i need to write to start my service is

```
php bin/console server:run xxx.xxx.x.xx:port
```

and it's all set.

But then i was reading some documentation about the symfony web server, and this information is confusing me:

> The built-in web server is meant to be run in a controlled
>   environment. It is not designed to be used on public networks.

How i'm suppose to use this in my cloud environment? If i want to make this public, how should i start my REST service without using this built-in server?

What is equivalent to the "server:run" command? If i just put the code there, it will not work. I need to start the server for my REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivaluent of the `server:run` command in a production environment is a bit more involved. The web server on a public facing machine has more responsibility than a local development server, and so it needs a bit more configuration.

For production (or even staging) purposes, use a production-ready web server like [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) or [Nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx).

I'll share a default setup for apache, on a Debian-based (Ubuntu) system here, and detail a few common pitfalls to avoid.

1. **Install LAMP components**

   `ssh` into your machine, and run this command to make sure that apache, php, mysql, etc, are all installed!

   First, get the most recent data from the repositories:

   `sudo apt-get update`

   The LAMP components that you'll need to run symfony on:

   `sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt`

   Be sure to store down the root MySQL pass if it asks you for one. (in the event you didn't have it installed, yet.)
2. **Configure MySQL**

   `sudo mysql_install_db` to initialize MySQL's system/help tables, etc.

   `sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation` to drop test tables, reload privilege tables.

   Jump into the MySQL shell and create a user & db for your app.

   `mysql -u root -p`, and supply your root pw when prompted.

   `mysql> CREATE USER 'otuyh'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` will create your `otuyh` user with the password `password`.

   `mysql> CREATE DATABASE otuyh_app;` will create the database your app needs to run on.

   `mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON otuyh_app.* TO 'otuyh'@'localhost';`

   `mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
3. **Configure Apache (the production version of `server:run`)**

   Clone or upload your project to `/var/www/html`.

   Edit `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and change the line:

   `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web`

   This tells apache which directory to serve requests from the web folder of your app.

   Also, alter the line `ServerName white-macbook` to `ServerName example.com` where example.com is the domain name pointed at your server.

   Finally, add an `AllowOverride All` line in there, too, to explicitly state that your `.htaccess` file can also add directives for the web server.

   Drop an .htaccess file in your `web/` folder that looks something like this:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       Options +FollowSymlinks
       RewriteEngine On

       RewriteBase /

       # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
       RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       # Change below before deploying to production
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

   Alter `app_dev` to just `app`, when you're ready to change the environment to production.

   Make sure you restart the apache2 service after having altered it's config: `sudo service restart apache2`.

   Run your regular sf2 schema creation, composer install, etc.

   And then, make sure that the apache user that serves the files up indeed has access to them!

   Additionally, after running `composer *` or `cache:clear` as a user other than the one serving files, write permissions can get mixed up, and `www-data` will need this privilege to write logs, and get cached files. A quick solution:

   `chown -R your-unix-user:www-data ./app`
   `find ./app/cache -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`
   `find ./app/logs; -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`
   `find ./app/cache -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \`
   `find ./app/logs -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \`

Comment: I did pretty much everything you said, but a couple of things: AllowOverride All inside the VirtualHost is not allowed, and when i'm trying to access my domain, is giving me HTTP ERROR 500. I really apreciate your help, but it's not working yet =(

Comment: Additional info: my project has nothing using default symfony architecture. The only thing it has is FOSRestBundle stuff that only works when i start my local web service. Without it, my project has nothing. It's a big web service that i need to start and i don't know how.

Comment: Another thing: when i'm trying to access my project locally without start the server, it's returning a 404 json, not a HTML response of 500. 
{
error: {
code: 404,
message: "Not Found"
}
}

Comment: Ok, it's working after i give 777 permission in the cache and log folder! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Awesome! There are always a few "gotchas" when it comes to permissions, I find. I'll amend the answer to include the issues you're raised in the comments, here. Very glad this worked for you, with a couple tweaks!

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned the built in Webserver is for Development only.
It is slow and open to all kinds of attacks.
You can run your Service like any other application with a Webserver.
There is a guide on the Symfony site that shows you how to do that.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html

Or if you have root access to your cloud server you can configure your Webserver

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: But what is equivalent to the "server:run" command? Because if i just put the code there, it will not work. I need to start the server for my REST API.